Limit of an alternating series (-1)^(n-1)/(n+i)
What is the limit of $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+…+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
My idea was to group together terms in pairs so that terms were decreasing and positive, then use the idea that the sum tends to the integral. But obviously I’d have to consider the even and odd case separate (and show they converge to the same limit). I think my method could work, but I was wondering if there’s a neater way

This is part of the tail of a converging series (the alternating harmonic series), so it has to go to zero.

One may write, for $n\geq 1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+…+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1x^{n+k-1}\:dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}x^{n+k-1}\:dx\\
&=\int_0^1x^{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-x)^{k-1}\:dx\\
&=\int_0^1x^{n}\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}\:dx\\
\end{align}
$$ then observe that
$$
\left|\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}\right|\leq\frac{2}{1+x}\leq 2,\,\,\, 0\leq x\leq1,
$$ giving
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+…+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}\right|=\left|\int_0^1x^{n}\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}\:dx\right|\leq2\int_0^1x^{n}\:dx=\frac2{n+1}
$$The conclusion is clear as $n$ goes to infinity.

We have that
$$\frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n+k+1}=\frac{1}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$
then for $n=2N$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+…+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n} \le N\frac{1}{(2N)^2} =\frac1{4N} \to 0$$
and for $n=2N+1$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+…+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}  \le\frac1{4N} +\frac{1}{4N+2}\to 0$$

Would the second inequality still hold if n is odd?

I wrote things thinking to $n$ even but we can of course extend the result. I fix that! Thanks
